# fpdf generate multiple pages using a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, fpdf

I'm new to fpdf and I have this short code that prints the values of an array. My problem is that I can't figure out how to output these value on separate pages.

My code:

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();

//Create an array
$myarray = array(1,2,3);

//loop through the array with a foreach and print the results on different pages
foreach($myarray as $value)
{
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);  
$pdf->Cell(40,10,$value);
$pdf->Output();

}
```

?>

Currently the code only prints the first value and stops. Your assistance is highly valued.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must invoke the output function outside of your foreach. In your function it's invoked at the first cycle and interrupt the cycle to the first time.

```
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();

$myarray = array(1,2,3);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);  
foreach($myarray as $value){
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,$value);
}
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Thanks jedi, I've invoked the output func ouside the loop and I can have 3 seperate pages, however I'm getting blank pages.

Comment: I have tryed now the snippet code making copy&paste on localhost and it's work. I have 3 page the first whit 1, the second with 2 and the third with 3. Do you have other code that interract?

Comment: I'm sorry for beeing a fool. It was my browser kinda slow on processing the output. I was using Firefox to test but I've switched to Chrome and everything is working out well. Thanks buddy.